# PHP Password_Hash Function

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I've been reading up on the usage of the PHP Password_Hash Function it states that it automatically generates a salt and manually generating one is not advised.

With this in mind, does this mean I can execute the following code:

```
    $password = password_hash('mypassword', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

creating a hashed and salted password that needs nothing further doing to it other than storing into a MySQL table column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`password_hash` generates both the salt and the hash. **It then combines them into a single string**, so you don't have to store them separately, like it's usually done.

That's also why [`password_verify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) takes only two parameters: a password and a combination of salt and hash.

Generating your own salt is not advised because you might do it wrong. For example, you could create one incorrectly by generating a predictable string or making it too short.  Additionally, **since the `password_hash` function already does that, why bother?** If the user changes the password then usually both the hash and the salt are regenerated.

Comment: Does this mean that the api uses the same salt for all passwords ?
I thought a salt was to be stored separately to add to the password and then to generate the hashed password. 
How does the verify_password function know what salt to add to the password ?
I am probably missing something fundamentally here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can then retrieve it and use password_verify() to check to see if a user-supplied password matches the stored hash.